# How to convert 3D Obj file to adjacency matrix of a graph matrix

Tags: python, 3d

I have a 3D OBJ file I would like to convert it to adjacency matrix of a graph. I know that adjancent matrix repersent if there is an edge between vertices, giving the OBJ file has faces indices, how would I convert it to adjacnet matrix ?

OBJ File gives

**Vertices, and Faces as indices of triangles.**

So I would like giving the vertices and faces information a graph like that:

```
gr2 = {
    1 : [2, 6],
    2: [1, 3],
    3: [2, 4, 7],
    4: [3, 5, 8, 9],
    5: [4, 6, 8],
    6: [1, 5, 9],
    7: [1, 3],
    8: [4, 5, 6],
    9: [3, 6]
}
```

Comment: can you show us  the input file and expected output?

Comment: @JakubDóka The input file has Vertices and Faces information. The question how would I use that information to construct an adjanceny matrix

Comment: @JakubDóka I edited the question

Comment: this does not really look like 3D obj file

Comment: oh i get it, will figure it out in a sec

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so you want this?

```
cf = open("cube.obj")

vertices = []
faces = []

def valid(a):
    return a.strip() != ""

def spl(a, fn):
    return list(map(fn, filter(valid ,a.split(" "))))
    

for l in cf:
    if l[0] == "v":
        vertices.append(spl(l[2:], float))
    if l[0] == "f":
        faces.append(spl(l[2:], int))

graph = {}

for f in faces:
    for i in f:
        if not i in graph:
            graph[i] = set()
    graph[f[0]] |= set(f[1:])
    graph[f[1]] |= set([f[0],f[2]])
    graph[f[2]] |= set(f[:2])

for g in graph:
    print(g, ":", graph[g])
```